# JQuery draggable intersect is being thrown off by margin

Tags: jquery, draggable, margin

I have a draggable with a large margin and a tolerance of intersect.  When I drag it to the droppable box, most of the time it works.  However, if I try to drop it near the TOP of the droppable box, it does not drop properly because the margin is calculated as part of the height.

Could someone suggest a workaround for this?  I tried removing the margin at the start of drag, but that results in a weird jumping of the draggable when you first grab hold of it.

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move'
})

$( ".droppable" ).droppable({
tolerance: 'intersect',
drop: function( event, ui ) {
$( this )
.addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
.find( "p" )
.html( "Dropped!" );
}})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wQvWK/6/

Comment: I could not get it to drop properly in your fiddle at all.

Comment: +1 for adding code and fiddle, with clear description

Comment: Tolerance is a property of droppable, not draggable. look at this bug report: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/2304. curisouly its reported and closed as fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.. The drop test is coded manually in order to work with the margin you have set.

```
var marginTop = 150;
$(".draggable").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move',
        stop: function(event, ui){
            if($('.droppable').position().top-$(this).height()/2 < ui.position.top+marginTop
              && $('.droppable').position().top+$('.droppable').height() > ui.position.top+marginTop+$(this).height()-$(this).height()/2
              && $('.droppable').position().left-$(this).width()/2 < ui.position.left
              && $('.droppable').position().left+$('.droppable').width() > ui.position.left+$(this).width()-$(this).width()/2) 
               {
                $('.droppable')
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                .find( "p" )
                .html( "Dropped!" );
            }
        }
    });
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/wQvWK/5/

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the matter and I believe that you will need to either drop the margin (do margin bottom on element above it)  OR monkeypatch the jQuery ui code to account for margin in this case.

I moved the tolerance of the `droppable` in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wQvWK/2/
Before I did this, it never dropped.

```
 $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
   tolerance: 'intersect',
 drop: function( event, ui ) {
 $( this )
.addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
.find( "p" )
.html( "Dropped!" );
}})
```